# How to add docker image to existing DockerFile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an existing docker container application where I now want to add the hashcat binary. To do this requires some dependencies such as nvidia drivers installed, so I cannot simply just place the binary in my image. I am attempting to use this https://github.com/dizcza/docker-hashcat docker hashcat implementation in my own image.

While I can get the docker-hashcat image to work fine on its own, I am struggling to add it to my existing project. I have tried the following DockerFile for my build (note, I already have the nvidia drivers installed on my machine):

```
#may need to change tag to :nvidia-full in case proper nvidia drivers not installed
FROM dizcza/docker-hashcat:latest

#use python image from 2.7
FROM python:2.7

ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# create unprivileged user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' myuser
RUN chown -R myuser:myuser /app
RUN chmod -R 755 /app
```

however, this dockerfile does not actually include the hashcat directory in my `/`.

I then tried moving my `FROM dizcza/docker-hashcat:latest` to the bottom of my dockerfile because I figured it was getting overwritten. However If I do that, I get the working hashcat directory and binary, but my project under `/app` does not exist in the image (running `docker-compose run service bash`). I can provide the service definition if needed that is in my `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files from another image to your image. In your Dockerfile:

```
COPY --from=dizcza/docker-hashcat:latest somefile somefile
```

Comment: So this successfully brings the hashcat folder over now, but it doesn't seem to properly install everything as I get an nvidia driver error

Comment: You need to install (or copy) the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app trying to run hashcat? Instead of trying to copy dizcza/docker-hashcat into your image, perhaps your app should just run container(s) with the dizcza/docker-hashcat as needed.